# Android Studio ArcticFox 2020.3 Issue in building the Flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated Android Studio to ArcticFox 2020.3.1.

my **app/build.gradle** looks like

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
//sourceCompatibility = 1.8
//targetCompatibility = 1.8

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "clubroom.android.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        //to support large number of references from the firebase console in to the app it self
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //signingConfig System.getenv('ANDROID_DEBUG') ? signingConfigs.debug : signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
//    compileOptions {
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    ///
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    //
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.0.0'
}
```

my **android/build.gradle** looks like

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
//        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
//        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my **gradle-wrapper.properties** looks like

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

JDK is set to version 13.

When I try to debug the app, I get this error
**

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/jasondwaku/Documents/FlutterProjects/ClubRoom/clubroom/android/app/build.gradle' line: 37
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_1m5d2vse17i1x8pxm6afu5q0a.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1m5d2vse17i1x8pxm6afu5q0a$_run_closure2) values: [build_1m5d2vse17i1x8pxm6afu5q0a$_run_closure2@704e3c1b]

**

Can someone help me to fix this issue, and how?

Answer (score 0):

insert to your gradle.properties :

```
org.gradle.java.home=<your jdk path>
```

hope fix your issue